# Compact set and total boundedness, confusion with definition

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

In Conway's *Functions of one complex variable I* the following definition of *total boundedness* is given:

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space;

For every $\epsilon>0$ there are a finite number of points $x_1, ..., x_n$ in $X$ s.t.

$X = \cup_{k=1}^{n}B(x_k;\epsilon).$

Then we have the following theorem:

$X$ is compact iff $X$ is complete and is total bounded.

My confusion comes from the definition of total boundedness using $=$ and not $\subset$.

For example if we take the metric space $([0, 1], d)$, the theorem above implies there is a finite union of open sets that is equal to our metric space. If that is the case can someone show me an example of the construction of such a finite collection of open sets?

I am confused because any union of open balls is an open set so I do not understand how a finite union of open sets can equal our metric space (I know our set [0, 1] is open and closed). For me the $\subset$ operator makes sense but not the $=$.

I am pretty sure I am missunderstanding something.

Comment: Total boundedness applies to entire metric spaces. If you want to apply it to $[0, 1]$, as a subset of $\Bbb{R}$, then you need to consider $[0, 1]$ as a subspace. So, all of the open sets involved are relatively open in $[0, 1]$, for example $(0.7, 1]$ is open.

Comment: $X = \cup_{k=1}^{n}B(x_k;\epsilon)$ IS  SAME AS $X \subset \cup_{k=1}^{n}B(x_k;\epsilon).$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When considering metric space $(X, d)$ all balls are contained in $X$, as they are defined by $B(x, r) = \{y \in X: d(x, y) < r\}$.

In the case of $[0, 1]$, you could write
$$
[0, 1] = \bigcup_k B(k/n, 1/n) = [0, 1/n) \cup (0, 2/n) \cup (1/n, 3/n) \cup \ldots (1-2/n, 1) \cup (1 - 1/n, 1]
$$

Answer (score 5):

The catch is that we are considering open sets in the relative topology, that is, open sets of the total space intersected with $[0,1]$.

An example of expressing $[0,1]$ as such an union could be $$[0,1]=[0,1/2)\cup (1/4,3/4)\cup (1/2,1]$$

Notice that $$[0,1/2)=(-1,1/2)\cap [0,1], \quad(1/2,1]=(1/2,2)\cap [0,1],$$

with both $(-1,1/2)$ and $(1/2,2)$ being open in the standard $\mathbb{R}$ topology.